# Is there a a way to change the default content-type to all Bottle's error responses at once?

Tags: json, python-2.7, bottle

I'm creating a small REST API in Bottle.

I only want to return JSON via the response, and although I could use the error decorator @error(status_code) for every HTTP status code there is, so it outputs JSON, I find this quite lengthy and not very practical.

Does anybody know a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I think I have managed a way to do this, although I don't know how memory/programmatically efficient it is:

```
import bottle
import json
app = bottle.default_app()  # or bottle.app()

for http_code in bottle.HTTP_CODES:
    @app.error(http_code)
    def json_error(error):
        bottle.response.default_content_type = "application/json"
        return json.dumps(dict(error=error.status_code, message=error.status_line))
```